# Trying to get property 'password' of non-object Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a login page where I am checking for the password. This method was working a while ago but now it is giving me the following error:

```
Trying to get property 'password' of non-object
```

The problem is in the retrieving and checking of the hashed password. However, I cannot find the error. Could someone help me out.
My code is as follows:

```
 public function logs_in(Request $request){
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');


    $hashedPassword = User::where('email', $email)->first();


    if(Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword->password)){
        $request->session()->put('success');
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('login_error', 'Invalid 
        credentials entered');
    }
}
```

Comment: `dd($hashedPassword)` and see if it is set and contains the password field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means there is no user with given email in DB and the result of this query is `null`:

```
User::where('email', $email)->first()
```

So, change the code to:

```
if ($hashedPassword && Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword->password)) {
```

Or use the `optional()` helper:

```
if (Hash::check($password, optional($hashedPassword)->password)) {
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!!